# Given an class selector of a div need to change the class name of previous hmtl tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have two html tags like this:

```
<Section class="class_name1"></section>
<div class="class_name2"></div>
```

I want to change class_name1 using selector class_name2 in js or jquery.
Can you please help ?

Comment: You are a new contributor and welcome, but as @Pedram mentioned, this not how you ask a question. You should not ask for a whole project or code. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.class_name2').prev().removeClass('class_name1').addClass('Add Class Which you want');
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Next time have a look at the jQuery documentation before you post on StackOverflow: [https://api.jquery.com/prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Your selector would be

```
$(".class_name2").prev();
```